# Submitting Spark AR effect to Instagram

Tags: facebook, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I am new to spark AR studio. I have built an effect which I am successfully able to submit to facebook and test it. But I have trouble submitting my effect to instagram.

I have linked my Instagram to Facebook as per the [steps](https://help.instagram.com/356902681064399?helpref=related&ref=related). Then while submitting effect via Spark AR hub, it won't allow me to choose **Effect Destination**.

I have properly checked the linking as well as refreshed the Spark AR hub after linking the accounts and even tried log out login again post linking.

Any pointers?

Comment: Having the same issue here. Have sent them a message but there's a potential they've closed the list of publishers they're allowing to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply to join the closed beta program. If accepted you will then be able to submit to Instagram.

Or you can wait until "this summer" when they open it to everyone.

Comment: I confirm. Right now it is open only to a subset of applicants and only for individuals (no companies or brands). Are there any more information about the "this summer" date? Can you post the link to the post?

Comment: This engadget article originally said anyone would be able to publish filters this summer, but now it seems to indicate the program is open to everyone already. https://www.engadget.com/2019/05/01/instagram-third-party-ar-filters/ Another article from later.com makes reference to the previous info saying this summer; https://later.com/blog/spark-ar-instagram/

Comment: update: the closed beta is over. [Everybody can know publish an effect](https://tech.fb.com/creativity-for-all-facebooks-spark-ar-now-lets-anyone-build-and-share-effects-on-instagram/) (including branded effects => linked to a fb page)